# Как правильно создать свой Layout наследуя LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Как создать свой `Layout` с элементами (`LinearLayout`,`Spinner`,`View` и т.п.) внутри так, чтобы управлять их расположением и анимацией?

**main_activity.xml**:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/window_1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/WindowSpinner_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/window_2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/WindowSpinner_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/window_3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/WindowSpinner_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/window_4"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/WindowSpinner_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.android.prog.CustomLayout>
```

класс **CustomLayout.java**:

```
public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout {

public CustomLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public void doSomefing{//Задаём действия с элементами внутри CustomLayout

}
}
```

Comment: Есть два способа. 1й - собственный элемент, в этом случае нужно создать свой класс наследуясь от LinearLayout, а в методе onCreate указать layout для своего элемента (или создать их программно).
2й метод - создать layout и импортировать его через include. 
Например в вашем примере можно повторяющиеся элементы выделить в отдельный layout файл и указывать через include.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу мой пример кастомного элемента, принцып подобный что и вам нужно:

```
public class BigText extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener  {
    int heightHide = -1;
    int heightShow = 0;
    boolean isShow = true;
    boolean isInit = false;

    TextView textView = null;
    View showView = null;
    View clickView = null;



public BigText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null, 0);
}

public BigText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs, 0);
}

public BigText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(attrs, defStyle);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_bigtext, this);

    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    showView = view.findViewById(R.id.show);

    clickView = view.findViewById(R.id.clickView);
    clickView.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    if(!isInit) {
        heightHide = getHeight();

        if (textView != null)
            heightShow = textView.getHeight();

        isInit = true;

        setShow(false);
    }

}


private void setShow(boolean show) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams mParam = getLayoutParams();

    if(heightShow <= heightHide)
        show = true;

    if(show)
        mParam.height = heightShow;
    else
        mParam.height = heightHide;

    isShow = show;
    setLayoutParams(mParam);
    requestLayout();

    clickView.setClickable(!isShow);

    if(showView != null)
        showView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(heightShow > heightHide || !isShow)
        setShow(!isShow);
}

public void setText(CharSequence text) {
    textView.setText(text);

    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            heightShow = textView.getHeight();
            setShow(false);
        }
    });
}

}
```

И layout этого элемента:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#ff333333"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:autoLink="email|web" />

</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/clickView">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:background="@drawable/view_bigtext_bottom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Показать больше"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />

    </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: спасибо. Да это помогло разобраться.